# Playlist search with libspotify : missing results

Tags: spotify, libspotify

We are trying to search for playlists via libspotify. We are using the search functionality to search by keyword with the following function :

search.html#ga2f64dfbcc1313e7d5179998cb28208d4">https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group_search.html#ga2f64dfbcc1313e7d5179998cb28208d4

Most of the time we are getting results. But some obvious playlists seems not to be matched.

For example we create a playlist in our own account with an almost unique name (which we are sure there won't be a lot of matches for). We then search for it and it does not appear in the results although we are using its name as keyword.  The playlists are publicly available.

Is there reasons for some playlists not to be searchable ?  Country restrictions ?  It does not seem to be related to its number of subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Spotify recently announced that there are over [one billion playlists](http://www.theverge.com/2012/12/6/3736140/spotify-five-million-paid-users) on the service.

With that large of a search pool, it'd simply be impractical to do playlist search "live". I'm not sure of the specifics since I'm not part of that team, but I'm fairly certain a playlist needs to be on the service for an amount of time before it gets included in the search index. Once your playlist is in the index, it should show up.

I don't have anything I can share regarding exactly how long it takes to be included in the search index, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes of course.  We also tested with playlists which are there for months.